# Redirect search result item to web part view not actual list

Tags: 2013, document-library, search

I have 4 document libraries (DLs) , each of them has been viewed in a web part with another page.aspx.

I have search center for all of those DLs, when the search result comes on the search page and when the user clicks any of the search result item, SharePoint redirects the user to the actual page of the document library.

what I need is, when a user clicks the search result item, SharePoint redirects him to the page that displays the document library in the web part.

Comment: This might be a subject of *event receivers*, which would handle the redirecting to the correct .aspx-page when the search result's URL includes the DL the .aspx is linked to.

Comment: Take a look at display templates, you can create a custom template that will contain a logic to change the search results url based on either content type or library name for those 4 document libraries.